# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Tags: java, class, jar, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to work with PHP-JavaBridge.

I want to access a Java class on Centos Tomcat7. Here's my PHP code:

```
require_once("/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
try {
    $spi= new java("ae.co.comtrust.payment.IPG.SPIj.Transaction");
    echo $spi;
} catch (JavaException $ex) {
  echo "An exception occured in First Block: "; 
  echo "<br>\n";
  echo $ex; 
  echo "<br>\n";
}
```

When I run this `http://example.com/test.php`, I am getting following error.

```
[[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new ae.co.comtrust.payment.IPG.SPIj.Transaction. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ae.co.comtrust.payment.IPG.SPIj.Transaction VM: 1.7.0_51@http://java.oracle.com/" at:
#-32 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
#-31 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
#-30 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
#-29 java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
#-28 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518)
#-27 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445)
#-26 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458)
#-25 php.java.bridge.Request.handleOneRequest(Request.java:510)
#-24 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.handleLocalConnection(PhpJavaServlet.java:202)
#-23 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.handlePut(PhpJavaServlet.java:250)
#-22 php.java.servlet.PhpJavaServlet.doPut(PhpJavaServlet.java:261)
#-21 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
#-20 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
#-19 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

Any help?

Comment: Where is the location of this jar file?  Did you make sure your project set up is correct?  Paths are all good?

Comment: I put Jar file in "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/ext"

Comment: And you're sure a class with that name exists in the jar file?

Comment: Yes it does. I checked it already.